# How do I sign out of Google on my iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, ios, google

How do I sign out of Google on my iPhone 7?  Everything I read tells you how to delete it or remove it, but I want to be able to use it later.  It appears that if you do not log out, Google merges your different Google drive accounts (personal/work).

Answer (score 1):

- Go to "Settings -> Passwords & Accounts"
- Select the account you want to remove from your iPhone
- Tap on "Delete account"

This will just delete the account *from* your iPhone. It will *not* delete the account itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tap the Google app
2. Tap settings icon on the top left corner
3. Tap manage google account
4. Tap remove account from this device
5. Tap remove

You can still sign in later by tapping Sign In under settings on the Google app